# ENTER_BR in CKEditor on enterMode does not work

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, config

I am having a ckeditor, where I am trying to set the behavior for the ENTER key to br tag instead of paragraph tag. I tried the following but nothing seems to be working:

```
enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,

autoParagraph: false,
```

Whereas the behavior for the SHIFT+ENTER key is set to br tag, I tried swaping these values to both these enterMode and shiftEnterMode but it is still the same.

Please suggests something!

Thanks!

Comment: should work, take a look at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-ENTER_BR .  When working on it, I didn't have to do the whole autoparagraph thing.  You can have inline config settings, & config.js settings, make sure those aren't conflicting.  The last thing I can suggest is to actually refresh the page, it'll be cached otherwise and not reflect your latest code. Also, out of context of the question, next time I need to deploy a text editor, ckeditor will be last on my list due to other issues it had (ex. it doesn't work in IE7 period).

Comment: Thanks! But yes I did refreshed and cached my page but no change. Also, what do you mean my inline config settings, & config.js settings?

Comment: There's a few ways to wire up ckeditor: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations .  These all apply in 4 as well.

Comment: If there's no change your problem lies outside the context of what you've provided, why not post all the code around your ckeditor implementation so we can help you better?  Stating the version you're using would be helpful too.  By inline I mean you can implement ckeditor on the page itself and configure all its settings, you can also JUST use the config file and put all your settings in there, did you read the link I gave you?